# QGIS aggregate intersects points in polygon by filtering values

Tags: qgis, filter, intersect, summarizing, aggregate

I have in QGIS 3.28 points and polygon layer.
I want to create virtual field that SUM on the point layer all the specific values the points intersecting in the polygon that are filtered according to the specified parameter (type_of_value). There are at point layer several types of features, I want to add only one type of features to SUM values.
This expression at polygon layer SUM all the values in the intersecting polygon layer.

```
aggregate(
layer:='points_layer', 
aggregate:='sum', 
expression:="values_to_sum", 
filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) )
)
```

One filter is missing in this expression ... type_of_value

Comment: `filter:=intersects( $geometry, geometry(@parent) ) AND "type_of_value" = 'my_parameter'` ?

Comment: thank you, it is working ... I tried 'type_of_value' instead of "type_of_value" ... and error?

Comment: A name in double quotes `"` refers to a fieldname and returns the value stored in this field/atrribute. A name in single quotes `'` is interpreted as a string and returns the exact string (characters) inside the quotes.